# Unable to use agrregate operators in MongoDB(storageEngine=mmapv1)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am getting following error while using `$convert` operator, mongodb storageEngine is **`mmapv1`**.

```
db.persons.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      registred: { $convert: { input: "registered.age", to: "double" } }
    }
  }
]);
```

> Error: command failed: { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "invalid operator
>   '$convert'", "code" : 15999 }

Comment: Which version of MongoDB are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operator [$convert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/) is available only for MongoDB versions >= 4.0.

That said, you have two options:

1- Updating you MongoDB

2- Converting the value on the result of the aggregation. In Javascript you could do the following:

```
var result = db.persons.aggregate([
    {
        $project:{
            registred:{
                $convert:{input:"registered.age",to:"double"}
            }
        }
    }
]);

result.forEach(
    function(document) {
        document.registred.age = parseFloat(document.registred.age);
    }
);
```